# Vuejs build hangs at "modules transformed"

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I have a VueJS 3 application which I'm trying to run on Rocky Linux,

I ran the following commands:

1. yarn install
2. yarn build

Then it hangs here:

```
vite v4.5.0 building for production...
✓ 875 modules transformed.
```

I also tried to use npm instead of yarn.

```
npm install
```

[image]

This is package.json

[image]

[image]

[image]